# Binary search in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search

I was wondering if I have any hidden bugs or traps in my code I wrote for an exercise.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

# define MAX 1000

int binSearch(int *arr, int arrSize, int num)
{
    int leftPos = 0, rightPos = arrSize - 1;

    while(mid != leftPos)
    {
        int mid = (rightPos + leftPos)/2;
        if(arr[mid] == num)
            return mid;
        else if(arr[mid] > num)
            rightPos = mid;
        else
            leftPos = mid;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(){

    /*testing program */
    int arr[MAX];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        arr[i]=rand()%100;

    sort(arr, arr+MAX);

    cout<<binSearch(arr, MAX, 4);

}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile. `min` must be defined before it is used.

Comment: if you'll replace `std::cout` with `printf()`, you will effectively have C program. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: using namespace std;, using that on the code review stack exchange requires a trigger warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Advice 1**

```
while(mid != leftPos)
```

Above, **`mid`** is not defined, so my compiler does not compile that.

**Advice 2**

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

I don't see your code using anything in **`stdio.h`**; why not remove it?

**Advice 3**

It seems that you forgot to *seed* the random number generator. Did you mean to

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

before creating the integer array?

**Advice 4**

```
int mid = (rightPos + leftPos)/2;
```

If **`rightPos + leftPos`** overflow, **`mid`** will end up negative. You can "extend the range" by writing

```
mid = leftPos + (rightPos - leftPos) / 2;
```

instead.

**Putting pieces together**

After a minor rewrite, your implementation may look like this:

```
int binSearch(int *arr, int arrSize, int num)
{
    int leftPos = 0, rightPos = arrSize - 1;

    // 'mid' not yet declared:
    int mid;

    while(leftPos < rightPos)
    {
        // Avoids overflowing '(leftPos + rightPos) / 2':
        mid = leftPos + (rightPos - leftPos) / 2;

        if(arr[mid] == num)
            return mid;
        else if(arr[mid] > num)
            rightPos = mid - 1;
        else
            leftPos = mid + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**Alternative implementation**

It is not hard to write the binary search as a template:

```
template<typename RandomIt, typename T>
RandomIt binarySearch(RandomIt begin, RandomIt end, const T& value)
{
    RandomIt save_end = end;

    while (begin != end)
    {
        auto range_length = std::distance(begin, end);
        RandomIt middle = begin;
        std::advance(middle, range_length / 2);

        if (*middle == value)
        {
            return middle;
        }

        if (value < *middle)
        {
            end = middle;
            std::advance(end, - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            begin = middle;
            std::advance(begin, +1);
        }
    }

    return save_end;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice! It would be better to take `value` as `const T&`.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I see you changed the expression in the while loop to "leftPos < rightPos" instead of leftPos != rightPos". Is there something wrong with my version of the expression ?

Comment: @SoloNasus If you pass a negative array length to your version (**`leftPos != rightPos`**), bad things will happen. (Try it.)